# SpEL KafkaListener. How can i inject custom deserializer through properties?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-el

I am using spring.
I have a configured ObjectMapper for the entire project and I use it to set up a kafka deserializer.
And then I need a custom kafka deserializer to be used in KafkaListener.

I'm configuring KafkaListener via autoconfiguration, not via @Configuration class.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomMessageDeserializer implements Deserializer<MyMessage> {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public MyMessage deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        return objectMapper.readValue(data, MyMessage.class);
    }
}
```

If i do like this

```
@KafkaListener(
    topics = {"${topics.invite-user-topic}"},
    properties = {"value.deserializer=com.service.deserializer.CustomMessageDeserializer"}
)
public void receiveInviteUserMessages(MyMessage myMessage) {}
```

I received KafkaException: Could not find a public no-argument constructor

But with public no-argument constructor in CustomMessageDeserializer class i am getting NPE because ObjectMapper = null. It creates and uses a new class, not a spring component.

@KafkaListener supports SpEL expressions.

And I think that this problem can be solved using SpEL.
Do you have any idea how to inject spring bean CustomMessageDeserializer with SpEL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no easy ways to do it with SPeL.

##### Analysis

To get started, see the JavaDoc for `@KafkaListener#properties`:

```java
/**
* 
* SpEL expressions must resolve to a String ...
*/
```

The value of `value.deserializer` is used to instantiate the specified deserializer class. Let's follow the call chain:

1. You specify this value in the `@KafkaListener` annotation, then you are probably not creating a bean of the `ConsumerFactory.class`. So Spring creates this bean class itself - see `KafkaAutoConfiguration#kafkaConsumerFactory`.
2. Next is the creation of the returned object `new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(...)` as `ConsumerFactory<?,?>` using the constructor for default delivery expressions keyDeserializer/valueDeserializer = `() -> null`
3. This factory is used to create a Kafka consumer (The entry point is the constructor `KafkaMessageListenerContainer#ListenerConsumer`, then `KafkaMessageListenerContainer.this.consumerFactory.createConsumer...`)
4. In the `KafkaConsumer` constructor, the `valueDeserializer` object is being created, because it is null (for the default factory of point 2 above):

```java
if (valueDeserializer == null) {
     this.valueDeserializer = config.getConfiguredInstance(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, Deserializer.class);
```

5. The implementation of `config.getConfiguredInstance` involves instantiating your deserializer class via a parameterless constructor using reflection and your **String**  `"com.service.deserializer.CustomMessageDeserializer"` class name

##### Solutions

1. To use `value.deserializer` with your customized `ObjectMapper`, you must create the `ConsumerFactory` bean yourself using the `setValueDeserializer(...)` method. This is also mentioned in the **second Important** part of the [JSON.Mapping_Types.Important documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#serdes-mapping-types)
2. If you don't want to create a `ConsumerFactory` bean, and also don't have complicated logic in your deserializer (you only have `return objectMapper.readValue(data, MyMessage.class);`), then register `DefaultKafkaConsumerFactoryCustomizer`:

```java
@Bean
// inject your custom objectMapper
public DefaultKafkaConsumerFactoryCustomizer customizeJsonDeserializer(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {  
    return consumerFactory ->
            consumerFactory.setValueDeserializerSupplier(() ->
                    new org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer<>(objectMapper));
}
```

In this case, you don't need to create your own `CustomMessageDeserializer` class (**remove it**) and Spring will automatically parse the message into your `MyMessage`.
`@KafkaListener` annotation should also not contains the property `properties = {"value.deserializer=com.my.kafka_test.component.CustomMessageDeserializer"}`. This `DefaultKafkaConsumerFactoryCustomizer` bean will automatically be used to configure the default `ConsumerFactory<?, ?>` (see the implementation of the `KafkaAutoConfiguration#kafkaConsumerFactory` method)

Answer (score 1):

Here how it works for me:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${solr.kafka.topic}", containerFactory = "batchFactory")
public void listen(List<SolrInputDocument> docs, @Header(KafkaHeaders.BATCH_CONVERTED_HEADERS) List<Map<String, Object>> headers, Acknowledgment ack) throws IOException {...}
```

And then I have 2 beans defined in my Configuration

```
@Profile("!test")
@Bean
@Autowired
public ConsumerFactory<String, SolrInputDocument> consumerFactory(KafkaProperties properties) {
    Map<String, Object> props = properties.buildConsumerProperties();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, SolrInputDocument> result = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    String validatedKeyDeserializerName = KafkaMessageType.valueOf(keyDeserializerName).toString();
    ZiDeserializer<SolrInputDocument> deserializer = ZiDeserializerFactory.getInstance(validatedKeyDeserializerName);
    result.setValueDeserializer(deserializer);

    return result;
}

@Profile("!test")
@Bean
@Autowired
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SolrInputDocument> batchFactory(ConsumerFactory<String, SolrInputDocument> consumerFactory) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SolrInputDocument> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    factory.setConcurrency(2);

    ExponentialBackOffWithMaxRetries backoff = new ExponentialBackOffWithMaxRetries(10);
    backoff.setMultiplier(3); // Default is 1.5 but this seems more reasonable
    factory.setCommonErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler(null, backoff));

    // Needed for manual commits
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    return factory;
}
```

Note that the interface `ZiDeserializer<SolrInputDocument> deserializer`is my interface and `ZiDeserializerFactory.getInstance(validatedKeyDeserializerName);` returns my custom implementation of `ZiDeserializer`. And `ZiDeserializer` extends `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer`. This works for me